# Using JSON data in a view

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a pretty complex PHP/HTML view.  However, I recently changed my site to refresh automatically using AJAX.  It currently returns a JSON array, and I need to reproduce my View using that data.

Here is my AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        selected: updatefilters,
    });   
    function updatefilters(ev, ui){
        // get the selected filters
        var $selected = $('#selectable').children('.ui-selected');
        // create a string that has each filter separated by a pipe ("|")
        var filters = $selected.map(function(){return this.id;}).get().join("\|");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'updatefilters',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: { filters: filters },
            success: function(data){
                var html = "<div id ='board'><table>";
                for (i=0 ; i< data.length ; i++)
                {
                     html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].subject + "</td><td>" + data[i].body + "</td></tr>";
                }
                html += "</table></div>";
                $('#board').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<div id='board'>
<?php
if ($threads)
    {
        $count = count($threads);
        $perpage = 17;
        $startlist = 3;
        $numpages = ceil($count / $perpage);
        if ($page == 'home') {$page = 1;}
        $threadstart = ($page * $perpage) - $perpage;
        $i = 0;
        echo "<table class='board'>
    <tr>
            <th width='5%'><img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/category_icon.png' alt='category_icon'/></th>
            <th width='5%'>Tag</th>
            <th width='50%'>Subject</th>
            <th width='7.5%'>Author</th>
            <th width='7.5%'>Replies/Views</th> 
            <th width='15%'>Last Post</th>
    </tr>";
        foreach ($threads as $list) 
        {   $i++;
            $thread_owner = $this->thread_model->get_owner($list['owner_id']);
            $thread_id = $list['thread_id'];
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT f.tag FROM filter_thread AS ft
                                        INNER JOIN filter AS f ON ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
                                        WHERE thread_id = $thread_id");
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $trunc_body = $this->thread_model->get_reply_summary($thread_id);
            $filter = "";
            $filter2 ="";
            $ent = "entertainment";
            foreach ($result as $string)
            {
                if ($string['tag'] == $ent) {
                    $filter2 .= "<div id='entertainment'><p>";
                    $filter2 .= "<img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/entertainment_icon.png' title='Entertainment' alt='Entertainment'/>";
                    $filter2 .= "</p></div>";
                } else {
                $filter2 .= "<div id='misc'><p>";
                $filter2 .= "<img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/misc_icon.png' title='Misc' alt='Misc'/>";
                $filter2 .= "</p></div>";
                $filter .= " [".$string['tag']."]";
                }
            }
            if (!$result) { $filter = "" AND $filter2 =""; }
            if ($i > $threadstart AND $i <= $threadstart + $perpage) 
            { 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$filter2."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$filter."</td>";
                echo "<td title='".$trunc_body['0']['body']."'><a href=".base_url()."main/thread/".$list['slug'].">".ucfirst($list['subject'])."<div id='filter'><p></p></div></a></td>"; 
                echo "<td><p>".$thread_owner."</p></td>";
                echo "<td align='right'>Replies: ".$list['replies_num']."<br>Views: ".$list['views']."</td>";
                $owner = $this->thread_model->get_owner($list['last_post_id']);
                echo "<td>".$owner." <br>".$list['replystamp'] ."</td></tr>";   
            }  
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Current Page: $page | ";    
        echo "Page: ";

        for ($n = 1; $n < $numpages+1; $n++) 
        {
            echo "<a href=".base_url()."main/home/$n>$n</a> | ";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

is there a not too hard way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Thanks for the start. how do i get the JSON data in there?

Comment: You looking to send HTML in your JSON or are you looking for a completely data-driven approach? If you just send the raw data in JSON and handle inserting the data in the HTML on the frontend, you can keep all that HTML out of the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` at the TOP of your PHP file.

Also, move the `<div id='board'>` to a variable inside the script - AFTER the `header()` function.

Furthermore, change all `echo`'s to variables, put those variables in an array, and use

```
json_encode($array);
```

Example:

```
$output = "<div id='board'>";

$output .= "<table class='board'>
    <tr>
            <th width='5%'><img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/category_icon.png' alt='category_icon'/></th>
            <th width='5%'>Tag</th>
            <th width='50%'>Subject</th>
            <th width='7.5%'>Author</th>
            <th width='7.5%'>Replies/Views</th> 
            <th width='15%'>Last Post</th>
    </tr>";

echo json_encode( array('output'=>$output) );
```

Comment: I guess the part that confuses me is that I do not currently have the javascript in the same View as the HTML.  

rickymason.net/letschat/main/home  <- the site should help get a better idea as to whats going on.  When you click a category, it fetches data then I have to build the HTML using the view.  I'm not still following where the AJAX should be, and where the PHP file enters the whole equation.

Comment: Ricky, what you need is a good HTML templating solution, one like mustache where you indicate where your data goes in an HTML template. `{"subject":"The subject","Author":"John"}` could then go in the template `<div class="author">{author}</div><div class="subject">{subject}</div>`.  I don't have the PHP knowledge to give you a really great example, but you could start there. Google mustache or HTML templates.